# Postgres 9.4 Geo Lookup with IPV6 INET

Tags: postgresql-9.4

I have two table in postgres 9.4.

- table1 includes records from website visits.

1. table1 has three columns: IP(type INET and IPV6 addresses), date, event_id and receives ~ 50K records a day.

   ||ip||date||event_id||
   |300:401:149:8000::|20231128|881948183929899|

- table2 contains geo lookup data in the form of ranges

1. table2 has 3 columns: start_ip, end_ip, country. There is an index set on start_ip and end_ip. It contains 300MM records. The start_ip and end_ip can go over multiple ranges.

   ||start_ip||end_ip||country_code||
   |100:0:0:1::|600:803:29b:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff|**|
   |2605:ffc1::|2606:3f:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff|us|
   |2609:e400::|260b:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff|us|

The final output needs to be a join of all data points when table1.ip is between table2.start_ip and table2.end_ip. My problem is due to the size of the dataset, and the type, my queries keep timing out. I have tried multiple join types. While cross join is the fastest on a small data set when I try to run on the full data set

simple things like the following are too slow:

```
select * from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.ip between t2.start_ip and t2.end_ip
```

I have also tried converting the first octet to bits to reduce the size of table2 before comparison  but it is not that valuable. I would love to use max(start_ip) but 9.4 does not support it.